# Aws Sagemaker invoke-endpoint call and csv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

i've created a clustering model on sagemaker and i'm invoking it via CLI with this command: 
aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint --endpoint-name myendpoint --body  $mydata --content-type text/csv output.json --region eu-west-1

If my data starts with a negative number, i get an error
"usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
  aws  help
  aws   help
aws: error: argument --body: expected one argument"

While if it's a positive number, everything works. How can i escape the first minus of the data to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that aws cli is treating your input data as another option because negative sign and hyphen are the same.

Have you tried to use `quotes before and after $mydata`?

For example, instead of:

```
sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint --endpoint-name myendpoint --body -2,1,2 --content-type text/csv output.json --region eu-west-1
```

use:

```
sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint --endpoint-name myendpoint --body "-2,1,2" --content-type text/csv output.json --region eu-west-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you use AWS Sagemaker's provided image for clustering? If you provided your own, you should be able to modify the inference code to expect the input data to have a header row. Then modify `$mydata` to include column headers which should avoid this issue you're seeing with negative numbers.